# Magento2 : Admin Url 404 Error Found

Tags: admin, magento-2.2.5

When I am trying to access admin URL it gives 404 error page in magento2.

Also, I tried to clean cache 
`rm -rf  var/cache/*` but not working

Comment: might be ht-access issue

Comment: take htaccess from working magento2 and paste it in your current website...

Comment: I checked htaccess is same as working magento2 could it be problem related to nginx?

Comment: Please confirm whether you are facing issue in local instance or server ?

Comment: I am facing issue in server

Comment: Try with {you_domain/index.php/admin_url}

Comment: Please check value of core_config_data by this query - SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'web/seo/use_rewrites'

Comment: If value is 1 then make it 0 and then enter url in your browser 
 base_url/index.php/your_admin_url

Comment: i got my issue it was due to index.php which got deleted from root folder